# OnCreateOptionsMenu not called for MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm following along on the Tutorial for fragments [here](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/TabView.cs) but unfortunately this tutorial doesn't show how to get icons into the menu bar.

I assumed I could just use a MenuInflater in the OnCreateOptionsMenu method but my code never appears to be hit when I put a debug there.

Here's what it looks like presently:

```
public class MainView : MvxTabsFragmentActivity
{

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    }

    public MainView()
        : base(Resource.Layout.Main, Resource.Id.realtabcontent)
    {

    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) {
        MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.main, menu);   
        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
    {
        AddTab<HomeView>("home", "", args, MainViewModel.Home);
        AddTab<ProfileView>("profile", "", args, MainViewModel.StartOrder);
        AddTab<CatalogView>("catalog", "", args, MainViewModel.Catalog);
        AddTab<CheckoutView>("checkout", "", args, MainViewModel.Checkout);
        AddTab<OrderHistoryView>("history", "", args, MainViewModel.OrderHistory);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?  Is there a different way to set the icons on the tab?  Everything shows up and navigates properly, I just have blank tabs...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `OnCreateOptionsMenu` has to do with setting the icons on the tabs - afaik that's just for 'right-click' or 'press-and-hold' menus?

If you want to use a TabSpec which also has an icon, perhaps consider using the other `AddTab` override which allows you to pass in a complete `TabSpec`

```
    // this is the call you are currently using
    protected void AddTab<TFragment>(string tagAndSpecName, string tabName, Bundle args,
                                     IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var tabSpec = this._tabHost.NewTabSpec(tagAndSpecName).SetIndicator(tabName);
        AddTab<TFragment>(args, viewModel, tabSpec);
    }

    // this is the call you could use instead
    protected void AddTab<TFragment>(Bundle args, IMvxViewModel viewModel, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec)
    {
        var tabInfo = new TabInfo(tabSpec.Tag, typeof (TFragment), args, viewModel);
        AddTab(this, _tabHost, tabSpec, tabInfo);
        _lookup.Add(tabInfo.Tag, tabInfo);
    }
```

e.g.

```
        var tabHost = (TabHost) FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);

        var tabSpec = this.tabHost.NewTabSpec("home").SetIndicator("Home", Resource.Id.MyHomeIcon);
        AddTab<HomeView>(args, MainViewModel.Home, tabSpec);
```

although obviously those last two lines could be reduced to one with a helper method.

Comment: Hey Stuart!  Thanks the icons show up now if I send in empty strings for the text!  I was using MenuInflater like they show in the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) documentation.